# How to prevent hibernate to use schema in generated sql

Tags: hibernate, jpa, oracle11g

I am using hibernate 4.2.12 with oracle 11g and I need to tell hibernate to not append any schema prefix in generated sql. So I remove from my entities any schema reference in the @Entity annotation. However, hibernate tool tries to validate my tables with SCHEMA.TABLE_NAME. In a try to force hibernate not to use the schema prefix I set the property "hibernate.default_schema" to an empty string in my persistence.xml and I turned off the schema validation. The application loads ok but when I try to execute any entity query the generated sql comes in this way: ".TABLE_NAME"! This causes the table does not exists error in oracle.

Have Anyone a solution or an ideia for this??

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it's too late to answer the question, but hoping that could help someone facing the same problem, I managed this in postgres 11 and hibernate 5 by setting postgres SEARCH_PATH on public schema and removing hibernate.default_schema option in hibernate configuration.

I think that you could do similar in ORACLE using synonyms.